# Unmarshalling xml file returns less data than expected on slice

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I'm using Go 1.14.4 to unmarshall an xml file I receive via an HTTPS request. I store the unmarshalled data into a variable and try to print what is inside it. The data retrieved is intact, as I have printed it and its whole. After unmarshalling the data seems to be clipped.

My Imports

```
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)
```

My Structs

```
type FoneRnpReply struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"list"`
    List    []Call   `xml:"firsttag"`
}

type Call struct {
    Id                int    `xml:"id"`
    SipCallId         string `xml:"sipCallId"`
    OriginNumber      int    `xml:"originNumber"`
    TargetNumber      int    `xml:"targetNumber"`
    OriginDDD         int    `xml:"originDDD"`
    TargetDDD         int    `xml:"targetDDD"`
    OriginInstitution int    `xml:"originInstitution"`
    TargetInstitution int    `xml:"targetInstitution"`
}
```

My main function

```
func main() {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    clienteDeRequisicao := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    var url = "some_url_to_grab_xml"

    resp, _ := clienteDeRequisicao.Get(url)
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //bodyString := string(bytes)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var s FoneRnpReply
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)    

    for i := 0; i < len(s.List); i++ {
        fmt.Println("Call ID " + strconv.Itoa(s.List[i].OriginNumber))
    }
```

Sample XML

```
<list>
  <firsttag>
    <id>1</id>
    <h323Id/>
    <sipCallId>qwdqwfqwfqwfqwf@111.111.11.1:2222</sipCallId>
    <originNumber>33333333</originNumber>
    <targetNumber>33333333</targetNumber>
    <originDDD>47</originDDD>
    <targetDDD>11</targetDDD>
    <originInstitution>12412412415</originInstitution>
    <targetInstitution>58568658</targetInstitution>
    <setupTime>
      <iMillis>346757547754</iMillis>
      <iChronology class="someAddress"/>
    </setupTime>
    <connectTime>
      <iMillis>1578399273000</iMillis>
      <iChronology class="someAddress"/>
    </connectTime>
    <disconnectTime>
      <iMillis>651468168468</iMillis>
      <iChronology class="someAddress"/>
    </disconnectTime>
    <duration>00:09:55</duration>
    <originType>SIP</originType>
    <targetType>SIP</targetType>
    <answered>true</answered>
    <callCompleted>true</callCompleted>
    <sipJustification>BYE</sipJustification>
    <h323Justification/>
  </firsttag>
</list>
```

Upon printing the parsed XML, just 5 values are returned, I was expecting 100:

```
Call ID 1
Call ID 2
Call ID 3
Call ID 4
Call ID 5
```

Comment: Check the error value from xml.Unmarshal

Comment: I've copied your code and put 7 xml objects. It looks like it works, so if you don't have all records, check Unmarchsall to error and check your input data.
https://play.golang.org/p/PxPXiiRYTGE

Comment: I'm new to go. Clearly. My mistake was, one of the fields of this HUGE xml I'm parsing should be an int, but was a string in one of the entries. This should serve as warning that if your parse is getting an error, and like me you are not capturing it, you might spend, like I did, 2 days figuring it out. Since I had some output, correct output, I assumed the parsing was occurring without problems. It wasn't.

Comment: If it is huge, you should not use unmarshal anyway, but [use stream parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53987338/1296707)